# More evidence needed than necessary for method using Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I was exploring Shapeless with a few colleagues yesterday, and we decided to write a toy method to add one to the first parameter of a case class, when that parameter is an `Int`:

```
def addOneToCaseClass[C, H <: HList, E, T <: HList]
    (c: C)
    (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[C, H],
              h:   IsHCons.Aux[H, E, T],
              ev:  E =:= Int,
              ev2: (Int :: T) =:= H
    ): C = {

  val hList = gen.to(c)

  val elem = hList.head
  val tail = hList.tail

  val newElem = elem + 1

  gen.from(newElem :: tail)
}
```

It seems to me that the `ev2` parameter is redundant - surely it can be inferred that `E :: T =:= Int :: T`, but the compiler was not able to make that happen.

Is there a particular reason why?

Comment: This in no way addresses your question, but does it work if you get rid of E entirely?  `[C, H, T]`, `IsHCons.Aux[H, Int, T]`, etc?  With E still present, any two of `h`, `ev`, and `ev2` should make it work-- do any of those combinations work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuitions are reasonable, but unfortunately the Scala compiler isn't quite clever enough to derive `ev2` from `h` and `ev`. The problem is that `h` only establishes that `H` decomposes to `E :: T`, it doesn't establish the converse, namely that `E` and `T` combine to equal `H`.

The tersest formulation of this that I can come up with is similar to your original, but has one less witness,

```
def addOneToCaseClass[C, R <: HList, T <: HList](c: C)
  (implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    h: IsHCons.Aux[R, Int, T],
    ev: (Int :: T) =:= R) = {
  val hList = gen.to(c)
  val elem = hList.head
  val tail = hList.tail
  gen.from(elem+1 :: tail)
}
```

Here we're able to eliminate the proof that `E =:= Int` by using `h` to show that `R` decomposes to `Int :: T`. However we still need to show that `Int :: T` is equal to `R` to move back across `gen` with the updated elements.

Comment: Had to remove my answer, and I hope this comment will not be deleted  by administration (as previous). So why we still have to use additional equality instead of just putting `(Int :: T)` instead of `R` (which actually compiles). Because [this migration doc](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Migration-guide:-shapeless-1.2.4-to-2.0.0#iso-is-now-generic) gives us example without `=:=`:  `def makeFoo[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit fooGen: Generic.Aux[Foo, L]): Foo = fooGen.from(l)` and explicitly says that it's impossible now, but `This limitation will go away in Scala 2.11`